# jquery autobrowse loading all the images

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jquery.esn.autobrowse.js plugin for infinite scroll but ran into problem.
The plugin is loading all the images at once. The problem seems the javascript is calling the url continuously by updating the offset without scrolling the page. Below is the HTML and PHP script. Thanks in advance for the help.

**GalleryPage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.esn.autobrowse.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.json-2.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jstorage.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="content">
<div id='gallery'></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
        $('#gallery').autobrowse(
            {
                url: function (offset)
                {
                return "getGallery.php?album_id=1&page="
                +Math.round(offset/20);
                },

                template: function (response)
                {
                    var markup='';
                    for (var i=0; i<response.items.length; i++)
                    {
                        markup+='<a href="'+response.items[i].photoID+'"><img src="'+response.items[i].Image+'" /></a>';
                    };
                    return markup;
                },
                itemsReturned: function (response) { return response.items.length; },
                offset: 0,
                max: 10000,
                loader: '<div class="loader"></div>',
                useCache: false,
                expiration: 1

            }
        );
 });
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**getGallery.php**

```
<?php

$count=20;
$offset=0;
if (isset($_GET['count'])) $count=$_GET['count']*1;
if (isset($_GET['page']))  $offset=$_GET['page']*$count*1;
$album_id=$_GET['album_id'];
$arr = array();
$sql="SELECT photo_id as photoID,thumbnail_location as Image FROM photos WHERE album_id = $album_id and published=1 ORDER BY orderId LIMIT $offset,$count";
//logToFile('Sql....'.$sql);
$rs = mysql_query($sql);

while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
$arr[] = $obj;
}

 echo '{"items":'.json_encode($arr).'}';

?>
```

If I turn on the logtoFile and see what is logged to file... I see all multiple sqls being executed at the initial page load itself as below.

```
Sql....SELECT photo_id as photoID,thumbnail_location as Image FROM photos WHERE album_id = 1 and published=1 ORDER BY orderId LIMIT 0,20
Sql....SELECT photo_id as photoID,thumbnail_location as Image FROM photos WHERE album_id = 1 and published=1 ORDER BY orderId LIMIT 20,20
Sql....SELECT photo_id as photoID,thumbnail_location as Image FROM photos WHERE album_id = 1 and published=1 ORDER BY orderId LIMIT 40,20
Sql....SELECT photo_id as photoID,thumbnail_location as Image FROM photos WHERE album_id = 1 and published=1 ORDER BY orderId LIMIT 60,20
Sql....SELECT photo_id as photoID,thumbnail_location as Image FROM photos WHERE album_id = 1 and published=1 ORDER BY orderId LIMIT 80,20
Sql....SELECT photo_id as photoID,thumbnail_location as Image FROM photos WHERE album_id = 1 and published=1 ORDER BY orderId LIMIT 100,20
Sql....SELECT photo_id as photoID,thumbnail_location as Image FROM photos WHERE album_id = 1 and published=1 ORDER BY orderId LIMIT 120,20
Sql....SELECT photo_id as photoID,thumbnail_location as Image FROM photos WHERE album_id = 1 and published=1 ORDER BY orderId LIMIT 140,20
Sql....SELECT photo_id as photoID,thumbnail_location as Image FROM photos WHERE album_id = 1 and published=1 ORDER BY orderId LIMIT 160,20
Sql....SELECT photo_id as photoID,thumbnail_location as Image FROM photos WHERE album_id = 1 and published=1 ORDER BY orderId LIMIT 180,20
Sql....SELECT photo_id as photoID,thumbnail_location as Image FROM photos WHERE album_id = 1 and published=1 ORDER BY orderId LIMIT 200,20
Sql....SELECT photo_id as photoID,thumbnail_location as Image FROM photos WHERE album_id = 1 and published=1 ORDER BY orderId LIMIT 220,20
Sql....SELECT photo_id as photoID,thumbnail_location as Image FROM photos WHERE album_id = 1 and published=1 ORDER BY orderId LIMIT 240,20
Sql....SELECT photo_id as photoID,thumbnail_location as Image FROM photos WHERE album_id = 1 and published=1 ORDER BY orderId LIMIT 260,20
Sql....SELECT photo_id as photoID,thumbnail_location as Image FROM photos WHERE album_id = 1 and published=1 ORDER BY orderId LIMIT 260,20
Sql....SELECT photo_id as photoID,thumbnail_location as Image FROM photos WHERE album_id = 1 and published=1 ORDER BY orderId LIMIT 280,20
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, yet it used to work.  I'm currently debugging!

Answer (score 0):

You can solved it with:

```
+Math.ceil(offset/20)
```

instead of

```
+Math.round(offset/20)
```